# Really can we exploit Bernoulli theorem to study Pitot tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

One of the assumption in proving Bernoulli theorem is that motion is laminar, the presence of turbulence will destroy the proof. Now, I can't believe that inside a Pitot tube the aren't turbolences: the fluid goes to crash against a flat surface (interface between two fluids). Really can we assume that motion is laminar? How can it be true that in books Bernoulli theorem is exploited to find quantitative results about Pitot tube? Isn't it more realistic to suppose that Pitot tubes are calibrated empirically and that in this context formulas obtained with Bernoulli theorem have a little to do with reality?

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately I don't know the exact answer, but will follow this question. The pitot tube fluid flow isn't laminar, perhaps an approximation with bernoulli's equation gives us close results?